# how to cleanly add transparent image planes, or overlay material, ontop of another mesh in 2.9

Tags: mesh, uv, eevee-render-engine, image

To add extra decal to my meshes that will only show up when I need them to, how do I add planes with an image to another mesh. Simple snap to face doesn't curve it and sticks out and shrink wrap deforms it way too much, also keeps trying to stretch it and attack to things not close to it. I know I can do a shape key like thing, tho I might have to, but then ill have tones of messy shape keys. So does anyone know of a way to smoothly, without deform, an image plane over a non-flat mesh, i.e. parts of a human or clothing. Also, this is for a toon/anime style animation, if that helps.

I'm using blender 2.9 and the eevee render engine.

sorry i should have given an example of what im going for. this is just one of the effects im hoping for.

[image]

Comment: Suggestion. See the topic of Blender UV Mapping with a mesh.  You can find perhaps a tutorial here at BSE or the famous video website that has a name that rhymes with noonoob.  Texture with transparency can be applied as a decal.  You might also search here at BSE with the search word decal.  Your searching skills are probably very good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material)

Comment: kind of but it doesn't seem to work with meshes already using UV, unless I'm stupid and missing something.

Comment: You can combine many materials as one, use masks and use one or many UVs. It is up to you. The biggest problem in adding geometry to add a texture on top of existing faces is that you will run into problems with **Z-fighting**, where two surfaces are coplanar and on top of each other. The render engine has a hard time differentiating what is in front of what.

Comment: I'll keep tinkering with it until I find something, if I find something.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that the better way to achieve your goal is the use of UV, materials, decals over the same mesh,  but if you really want to use a different mesh you can duplicate the object, add a solidify modifier with an appropriate factor, apply it and  delete the unuseful faces.

[image]

Comment: I want to use the most efficient, clean and organized method because I'm going to do animations with multiple characters, so that can get messy real quick, but I'ii still try it.

Comment: Also, your way does sound more like what I'm aiming for but how do I have control over the position of the decal. Some of the things I've tried deformed the image.

Comment: You should definitely get familiar with UV maps, which have been invented exactly to control textures over meshes.

Comment: K, I'll start looking into it but if you know of any tutorials that you like, then can you link it/them to me.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTd8NBg8EZU

Comment: Thanks, will start messing with it soon.